# iOS - Download Video

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, afnetworking

**I'd like to download a video from a remote URL and save it to a file in an iPhone app.**
I know the video link works, since I have used it from AVPlayer, however, I am unable to download it. The response is always (null).

What is wrong with the following code?

```
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:someURLString]];
    AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];

    operation.outputStream = [NSOutputStream outputStreamToFileAtPath:someFilePath append:NO];

    [operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        NSLog(@"Successfully downloaded file to %@", [NSURL fileURLWithPath:someFilePath]);
        NSLog(@"THE RESPONSE: %@", responseObject);
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
    }];

    [operation start];
```

---

Update

**I commented out the operation.outputStream line, and this time I got a response. Does this mean that there is something wrong with the file path?**

Comment: Is the file downloaded?

Comment: No, the operation is always "successful", but nothing is ever downloaded @H2CO3

Comment: Are you trying to download it to the app bundle?

Comment: No, to a folder within the Documents Directory @H2CO3

Comment: Maybe the file path. Log it and show how you generate the path, otherwise we're guessing...

Comment: @GangstaGraham I don't know what the problem could be, what if you try another file path? Also, what is the response?

Comment: 0e4e375c 215bc3e8 39df2e02 ac63b276 0b8ccb6b f60ea468 db1cd324 d95c2181 ebbf9a0a 69f4259f b0ca4a7e 834f4ec5 5dff1f67 c1c511e6 aaade50b 5ac5e13e and so on....... (basically movie data I'm guessing) @H2CO3

Comment: @GangstaGraham Well, I'd rather be intereated in its class instead, dumping arbitrary binary data is not too informative... But if it's NSData, then go ahead and write it to the file. If *that* errors out, then check the error.

Comment: @H2CO3 I am using [responseObject writeFileToPath:somePath atomically:YES], and it works 1 out of 10 times, so it's quite error prone for some reason

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what was going wrong.

I was using the url of the video, and as part of the file path.

Why is this wrong? It has backslashes, so I assume iOS was getting confused.

**Lesson learned: make sure that the string that you add to a directory to create a file does not have backslashes.**

I hope this helps anyone else who makes this silly mistake. :P

Answer (score 0):

just create a link to that file, then use NSURLConnection to download.

Create a URL connection to download:

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:strFileUrl]]; //strFileURL is url of your video/image
NSURLConnection *conection = [[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self startImmediately:NO] autorelease];
[conec start];
[request release];
```

Get path of file to save data:

```
strFilePath = [[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:strFileName];
```

Your class must adopt 3 methods of NSURLConnectionDelegate protocol: (please read about Protocol and Delegate)

```
   - (void) connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
    {
        // create 
        [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createFileAtPath:strFilePath contents:nil attributes:nil];
        file = [[NSFileHandle fileHandleForUpdatingAtPath:strFilePath] retain];// read more about file handle
        if (file)   {
            [file seekToEndOfFile];
        }
    }



 - (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)receivedata
    {    
        //write each data received
        if( receivedata != nil){
            if (file)  { 
                [file seekToEndOfFile];
            } 
            [file writeData:receivedata]; 
        }
    }

    - (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection*)theConnection {
        //close file after finish getting data;
        [file closeFile];
    }

    - (void) connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
    {
        //do something when downloading failed
    }
```

If you want to review you file, use a UIWebview to load it:

```
 NSURL *fileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:strFilePath];
    [wvReview loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:fileURL]];
```